# .NET - Windows Azure Queue question - background work on the queue

Tags: .net, asp.net, queue, azure

First let me say, I'm just starting to get up to speed on the Azure platform.

I understand how in the Azure Queue model a web interaction could put something in a queue and a later interaction could process it. But...

What is the equivalent of a "Windows Service" in the Azure world? What if I just wanted something in the background to work through the items in my queue... what is the correct approach for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a worker role which is a background process. The web server (web role) will talk to the worker role via a queue.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179341.aspx